# html submenus not showing below menu

Tags: html, css

In the below it's a menu with dropdown submenus.

In Chrome the sub-menus are appearing below the menu, but in Firefox and IE they are always appearing below the first item.

If I change the 'float: none' to 'float: left' it works and they appear below the menu, but all the sub-menu items become inline and flow one after the other.

Is there an easy fix (rather than modifying the html as this is generated from an xml file on the server - but I can modify if need be) in css?

Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

#cat_nav li > ul { display: none; }
#cat_nav ul{list-style-type: none;}
#cat_nav ul li {float: none; position: relative} /*change float to not none and it aligns but items are inline */
#cat_nav ul li:hover > ul {display: block;}
#cat_nav ul ul {min-width: 150px;background-color:#DFDFDF;padding:4px 0 4px 0;position:absolute;}

</style>


</head><body>

    <nav id="cat_nav">
    <ul class="products_btn">
        <li style="display: inline">
            <a href="">PCBS1</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li> <a href="x" title="Fuzz">Fuzz 1-1</a></li>
                <li> <a href="x" title="Fuzz">Fuzz 1-2</a></li>
                <li> <a href="x" title="Fuzz">Fuzz 1-3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li style="display: inline">
            <a href="">PCBS2</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li> <a href="x" title="Fuzz">Fuzz 2-1</a></li>
                <li> <a href="x" title="Fuzz">Fuzz 2-2</a></li>
                <li> <a href="x" title="Fuzz">Fuzz 2-3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body></html>
```

Comment: This `#cat_nav ul li` targets ALL `li`, if you want the submenu to do something else you would have to target them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `float:none` to the `float:left` on `#cat_nav ul li` and add this

```
#cat_nav ul li li {
  float:none
}
```

to un-float the list items within the list items (and thus appear stacked instead of inline).

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your selecting and positioning. I have made some small edits to your code with a working example tested in firefox. See below.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/RDQW8/1/

```
#cat_nav li > ul {
    display: none;
}
#cat_nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#cat_nav ul > li {
    position: relative
}
/*change float to not none and it aligns but items are inline */
 #cat_nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
#cat_nav ul ul {
    min-width: 150px;
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    padding:4px 0 4px 0;
    top:15px;
    position:absolute;
}
```